# How do I explicitly tell Hive a file is compressed?

Tags: hive, compression

I have Googled and read Hive docs, but can't find the answer I am looking for.

I read in many compressed (.gzip) files to an s3 bucket, but forgot to include the file extension. Hive determines whether a file is compressed based on the extension. Is there way to explicitly inform Hive that the files are compressed?

If not, what is the best way to go about adding the extension (other than manually from the s3 interface)? Using mv from the AWS CLI?